# How do I get an iPad like dock for ubuntu?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I am extremely new to Ubuntu and I just want to know how can I get an iPad like floating dock, like the one on macOS Big Sur,I got a lot of it down now I just wanna know how do I make the dock float a certain height from the bottom of the screen and how I can round off the corners of the dock a but more.

Comment: Not sure all these can be easily doable with the default Ubuntu Dock, you may have better luck trying the Deepin OS (or installing the Deepin desktop on Ubuntu).

Comment: Try Cairo Dock. I don't know if it's still available for Ubuntu but I found it quite configurable. Search for Cairo dock on software center and install it. Then play around with the settings.